# Book: Learning ROS for Robotics Programming, 2nd Edn; Chapter 4 example1 Not Working - dynamaximal driver not installed

Tags: ros, roslaunch, joy-node, joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I thoroughly followed all the instructions given on chapter 4 of the book (Learning ROS for Robotics Programming 2nd edition) on Jade. That's the error I am seeing ![image description]. I have also followed all the instructions given in ROS tutorials (http://wiki.ros.org/joy/Tutorials/WritingTeleopNode) but doing this giving me another type of error i.e. dynamaximal driver not installed. If possible please help me for any of it.

I am using ubuntu 15.04 on Jade. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223985/book:-learning-ros-for-robotics-programming,-2nd-edn;-chapter-4-example1-not-working---dynamaximal-driver-not-installed/) by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-01-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-12**:
I can't see the images you posted. Please edit your question to include your error messages as text. (The preformatted text button `010101` is good for this).

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-12**:
I have a suspicion that this is a CMake problem; when you update your question please also include your CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks ahendrix, I figured out this problem. The main problem was with the book. In the next section there was a tutorial about dynamaximal motors and package for its installation. As, I had not installed it, I was getting error because of it. I installed that package and it started working. Thanks for your kindness.

---

Originally posted by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) with karma: 167 on 2016-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0